# Issue with Informatica Loading into Partitioned Oracle Target Table

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I m facing a issue in regard to loading into Partitioned Oracle Target table.

We have 2 sessions having same table in Oracle as Target
     a. INSERT data into Partition1
     b. UPDATE data in Partition2

We are trying to achieve parallelism in the workflow, and there are more Partitions and sessions to be created for different data  but into same table, but different partitions..

Currently when we run both these sessions parallely, the Update session runs successfully, but the INSERT session gets a NOWAIT error.
NOTE: both are loading data for different partitions.

we made the mapping logic into 2 differnt stored procedures(one does INSERT, and another UPDATE), and they run parallely without any lock when executed from DB directly.

We tried mentioning the partition name in Target override too. but with same result.

Can you advice what are the alternatives we have inorder to achieve parallelism into same target table from Informatica.

Thanks in advance